# Is there anyway to find out the colour of the underlying view?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors

Im developing a floating app that will tell you the colour of the underlying app. Is there anyway to do this?.

Comment: What do you mean by 'color' of an underlying app ? An app can use different colors in the same view.

Comment: I mean it shows the color of the specific color its over. E.g. if the app is placed over two colours it will bring up a toast saying please place it over only one colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android sandboxes individual applications, so you can only interact with other apps through their exposed services - intents and content providers. [Read more.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)